# JQGrid - Manage pagination & column filtering without local data (loadonce = false)

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm having some issue with the development of my web application. I use Laravel 5.8 for the backend and JQGrid version 4.6.0 to build some grids.

I have a grid build with a dynamic URL called to fetch JSON data on the server side (URL depend on filters parameters informed). So the grid has `loadonce` attribute set to `false`.

My problem is that the pagination & the column filtering not working now and i imagine that i have to build a server side for every paginate and filtering features. But i'm not very sure because i did not find a concret example on how develop this.

I saw on the "Network Tab" of the Google Developer Tools that this URL is called for example when i want to sort by column : `http://localhost/projetMecenat/public/listes/cerfa/json/null?_search=false&nd=1621430296935&rows=5&page=1&sidx=NUM_CERFA&sord=asc` but i don't know how to exploit this.

If anyone has already dealt with this type of situation, i would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of docs and examples which describe this. You should just find and read them. I recommend you to start with the [docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs).

A MYSQL example with paging and sorting can be [found here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid&s%5B%5D=mysql)

This is for xml datatype, but I think you can adapt it for JSON.